# Excel VBA, code to count the # of filled cells, then find highest and 2nd highest and subtract the corresponding column #'s

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to count the # of items in a list from A11 to A90. And if that number is even subtract the max value from the 2nd max and then 3rd max from 4th max, etc.. If it's odd then it would start at the 2nd max minus the 3rd, and 4th to 5th etc.. Until all numbers have been subtracted from their counterpart.  The tricky part is that the numbers which need to be subtracted are in a different column, C11 to C90.

I'm basically trying to find the number of consecutive negative outcomes from column C  using the 2 closest values from column A.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by recording a macro that copys and pastes the data values into another section then I sorted it largest to smallest.

I then created a column with the equation to subtract one from the other.